# Doubts using Amazon S3 monthly calculator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to store videos and some audios (average size of 25 mb each) and users of my web and android app (so far) can access them with no problem but I want to know how much I'll pay later exceeding the free stage of S3 so I checked the [S3 monthly calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

I saw that there is 5 fields:

- **Storage:** I put 3 gb cause right now there are 130 files (videos and audios)
- **PUT/COPY/POST/LIST Requests:** I put 15 cause I'll upload manually around 10-15 files each month
- **GET/SELECT and Other Requests:** I put 10000 cause a projection tells me that the users will watch/listen those files around 10000 times monthly
- **Data Returned by S3 Select:** I put 250 Gb (10000 x 25 mb)
- **Data Scanned by S3 Select:** I don't know what to put cause I don't need that amazon scans or analyze those files.

Am I using that calculator in a proper way?

What do I need to put in "Data Scanned by S3 Select"?

Can I put only zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For audio and video, you can definitely specify `0` for S3 Select -- both data scanned and data returned.

[S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) is an optional feature that only works with certain types of *text* files -- like CSV and JSON -- where you make specific requests for S3 to scan through the files and return matching values, rather than you downloading the entire file and filtering it yourself.

This would not be used with audio or video files.

Also, don't overlook "Data transfer out."  In addition to the "get" requests, you're billed for bandwidth when files are downloaded, so this needs to show the total size of all the downloads. This line item is data downloaded from S3 via the Internet.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you Michael, then, I can put something like: 0 gb, 15 request, 10000 requests and 0, 0 for final two fields? Also, you put for Get requests: "..so this needs to show the total size of all the downloads" but that field ask for number of request and not Gb.

Comment: `Data transfer out` is the field I'm referring to.  This needs to reflect the total size of all downloads (typical size × number of `GET` requests).  Data scanned and data returned by S3 Select can both be 0.

Comment: Thank you Michael, now I understand. I still have some doubts about byte-hours cost but that is for another question :)

Comment: In S3, storing 30 GB for 1 day is the same cost as storing 1 GB for 30 days.  S3 bills in gigabyte-hours, so storing ~744GB for 1 hour (then deleting it) will cost you the same as storing 1 GB for an entire month, because both are ~744 GB-hours.  The net effect is that you pay for storage based on the average size of the entire bucket, each hour, over the month, at the listed price per GB.

Comment: Calculator is not applying free 100GB `Data transfer out` provided by aws. Is it something we need to assume ? And is it only available till the free tier i.e. 12 months ?